# My XML table shows but does not populate with text

Tags: xml, xslt

## THIS IS THE .XML FILE

This was provided and I am trying to create the .XSL file to populate the table with this (XML) file's information.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sigmod.xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE SigmodRecord [
<!ELEMENT SigmodRecord (issue)* >
<!ELEMENT issue (volume,number,articles) >
<!ELEMENT volume (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT number (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT articles (article)* >
<!ELEMENT article (title,initPage,endPage,authors) >
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT initPage (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT endPage (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT authors (author)* >
<!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST author position CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>

<SigmodRecord>
<issue>
<volume>11</volume>
<number>1</number>
<articles>
 <article>

<title>Annotated Bibliography on Data Design.</title>
<initPage>45</initPage>
<endPage>77</endPage>
      <authors>
<author position="00">Anthony I. Wasserman</author>
<author position="01">Karen Botnich</author>

      </authors>
 </article>

 <article>
<title>Architecture of Future Data Base Systems.</title>
<initPage>30</initPage>
<endPage>44</endPage>
      <authors>

<author position="00">Lawrence A. Rowe</author>
<author position="01">Michael Stonebraker</author>
      </authors>
 </article>

 <article>
<title>Database Directions III Workshop Review.</title>
<initPage>8</initPage>

<endPage>8</endPage>
      <authors>
<author position="00">Tom Cook</author>
      </authors>
 </article>

</articles>
</issue>
</SigmodRecord>
```

### This is the .XSL file

I am not sure if my Xpath is correct, I'm guessing it isn't and that's why my table won't populate but for some reason I cannot seem to figure it out...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="SigmodRecord">
<html>  
<body>  
<h2>Articles</h2>    
<table border="1">      
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">        
<th>Volume</th>        
<th>Number</th> 
<th>Title</th>  
<th>Start Page</th> 
<th>End Page</th>   
<th>Page Length</th>      
</tr>      
<xsl:for-each select="SigmodRecord/issue/articles/article">      
<tr>        
<td><xsl:value-of select="issue/volume"/></td>        
<td><xsl:value-of select="issue/number"/></td>  
<td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td> 
<td><xsl:value-of select="initPage"/></td>  
<td><xsl:value-of select="endPage"/></td>   
<td><xsl:value-of select="((endPage)-(initPage))"/></td>      
</tr>      
</xsl:for-each>   
</table>  
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure if my Xpath is correct, I'm guessing it isn't and that's
>   why my table won't populate

That's an accurate guess. Ttry it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>  
        <body>  
        <h2>Articles</h2>    
        <table border="1">      
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">        
                <th>Volume</th>        
                <th>Number</th> 
                <th>Title</th>  
                <th>Start Page</th> 
                <th>End Page</th>   
                <th>Page Length</th>      
            </tr>      
            <xsl:for-each select="SigmodRecord/issue/articles/article">      
                <tr>        
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="../../volume"/></td>        
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="../../number"/></td>  
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td> 
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="initPage"/></td>  
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="endPage"/></td>   
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="endPage - initPage"/></td>      
                </tr>      
            </xsl:for-each>   
        </table>  
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Note:
1. If you're running this in a browser, then you're using XSLT 1.0;
2. There's no need to use parentheses just to make a subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

Your template is already matching `SigmodRecord`, so you can e.g. change the for-each to

```
<xsl:for-each select="issue/articles/article">      
  <tr>        
    <td><xsl:value-of select="parent::articles/preceding-sibling::volume"/></td>        
    <td><xsl:value-of select="parent::articles/preceding-sibling::number"/></td>  
    <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td> 
    <td><xsl:value-of select="initPage"/></td>  
    <td><xsl:value-of select="endPage"/></td>   
    <td><xsl:value-of select="((endPage)-(initPage))"/></td>      
    </tr>      
</xsl:for-each>
```

With this adjustment following output is generated:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <h2>Articles</h2>
  <table border="1">
     <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Volume</th>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Start Page</th>
        <th>End Page</th>
        <th>Page Length</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Annotated Bibliography on Data Design.</td>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>77</td>
        <td>32</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Architecture of Future Data Base Systems.</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>44</td>
        <td>14</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Database Directions III Workshop Review.</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>0</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Because `value` and `id` are parent elements of each `article`, they can be selected by using

```
<xsl:value-of select="parent::articles/preceding-sibling::volume"/>
```

in the `xsl:for-each` loop.

Comment: This: `<xsl:value-of select="//issue/volume"/>` is incorrect; it will always get the value from the **first** issue in the entire document. -- As an aside, it's good practice (performance-wise) to avoid both `//` and `.//` constructs when the path is known.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks for considering, just adjusted for the obvious case of more than one record.

Comment: @JoshMcNatt Glad I was able to help you. If this answered your question, you can consider to accept this answer or one of the other answers so the question will be marked as closed/answered. As I noticed you're maybe new to Stackoverflow and don't know how this works and why, just check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235

Comment: Right. Note, however, that you are assuming that `volume` comes *before* `articles`. I don't see any need for such constraint.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sure, it depends on the input, but that's a different issue that you have already covered in your answer (as well as the unnecessary parentheses). Current OP issue was only the empty ouput of the `for-each`, and this seems to be resolved. Thanks again to point out possible pitfalls.